# Convert week number in dataframe to start date of week (Monday)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to convert daily data into weekly data. Here is the code I've used to achieve this

```
    daily_data['Week_Number'] = pd.to_datetime(daily_data['candle_date']).dt.week
    daily_data['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(daily_data['candle_date']).dt.year
    df2 = daily_data.groupby(['Year', 'Week_Number']).agg({'open': 'first', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'last', 'volume': 'sum', 'market_cap': 'sum'})
```

Currently, the dataframe output looks as below -

```
                          open          high           low         close        volume     market_cap
Year Week_Number                                                                                     
2020 31           11106.793367  12041.230145  10914.007709  11059.660924   86939673211   836299315108
     32           11059.658520  11903.881608  11011.841384  11653.660942  125051146775  1483987715241
     33           11665.874956  12047.515879  11199.052457  11906.236593  141819289223  1513036354035
     34           11915.898402  12382.422676  11435.685834  11671.520767  136888268138  1533135548697
     35           11668.211439  11806.669046  11183.114210  11704.963980  122232543594  1490089199926
     36           11713.540300  12044.196936   9951.201578  10277.329333  161912442921  1434502733759
```

I'd like the output to have a column `week_date` that shows the date of Monday of the week as the start date. Ex: Show 27-07-2020 in place of 31st week of 2020 and so on. It's this final piece that I'm stuck with really badly. Please could I request some help to achieve this.

**

- SOLUTION FOR THOSE WHO NEED

**

The entire function used to convert daily data to weekly below

```
   def convert_dailydata_to_weeklydata(daily_data):
        # Print function name
        SupportMethods.print_func_name()

        # Loop over the rows until a row with Monday as date is present
        row_counter_start = 0
        while True:
            if datetime.weekday(daily_data['candle_date'][row_counter_start]) == 0:
                break
            row_counter_start += 1

        # # Loop over the rows until a row with Sunday as date is present
        # row_counter_end = len(daily_data.index) - 1
        # while True:
        #     if datetime.weekday(daily_data['candle_date'][row_counter_end]) == 6:
        #         break
        #     row_counter_end -= 1
        # print(daily_data)
        # print(row_counter_end)

        # Copy all rows after the first Monday row of data is reached
        daily_data_temp = daily_data[row_counter_start:]

        # Getting week number
        daily_data_temp['Week_Number'] = pd.to_datetime(daily_data_temp['candle_date']).dt.week

        # Getting year. Weeknum is common across years to we need to create unique index by using year and weeknum
        daily_data_temp['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(daily_data_temp['candle_date']).dt.year

        # Grouping based on required values
        df = daily_data_temp.groupby(['Year', 'Week_Number']).agg(
            {'open': 'first', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'last', 'volume': 'sum', 'market_cap': 'sum'})

        # Reset index
        df = df.reset_index()

        # Create week date (start of week)
        # The + "1" isfor the day of the week.Week numbers 0-6 with 0 being Sunday and 6 being Saturday.
        df['week_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'].astype(str) + df['Week_Number'].astype(str) + "1", format='%G%V%w')

        # Set indexes
        df = df.set_index(['Year', 'Week_Number'])

        # Re-order columns into a new dataframe
        weekly_data = df[["week_date", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "market_cap"]]
        weekly_data = weekly_data.rename({'week_date': 'candle_date'}, axis=1)

        # Drop index columns
        weekly_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        # Return data by dropping curent week's data
        if datetime.weekday(weekly_data.head(-1)['candle_date']) != 0:
            return weekly_data.head(-1)
        else:
            return weekly_data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) on the 'Year' and 'Week_Number' columns with a format string for Year, Week of Year, and Day of Week (`'%G%V%w'`):

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['week_date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Year'].astype(str) + df['Week_Number'].astype(str) + "1",
    format='%G%V%w'
)
df = df.set_index(['Year', 'Week_Number'])
```

The `+ "1"` is for the day of the week. Week numbers 0-6 with 0 being Sunday and 6 being Saturday. ([Ref. Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes))

`df`:

```
                          open         close  week_date
Year Week_Number                                       
2020 31           11106.793367  11059.660924 2020-07-27
     32           11059.658520  11653.660942 2020-08-03
```

Comment: Thank you heaps Henry. Works as expected.

Comment: Hello Henry - Couple of modifications that i had to do are to skip the rows form the beginning until a Monday is reached for starters then also skip the rows from the bottom of the dataset until a Sunday is reached as my definition of week is Monday to Sunday

Comment: With or without this extra logic added, I see a random line at the end of the dataset which is  row with enty 2022-01-03. I can't decipher where this is coming from. I've updated the question with the random data line. Please can you help?

Comment: I've updated the question section with all the code I'm using

Comment: This update you've made is actually a separate question. The initial question was about converting a multi-index year and week to a Monday date value. Now the question is what's wrong with my specific implementation. I'd suggest you revert the changes you've made, and ask a _new_ question about _this_ problem. Also your error appears to be 2022, while your provided data only goes through 2020. Please (in your new question) include the specific lines of your current frame which are causing this issue.

Comment: Thanks Henry. I've created a new question for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67698959/daily-to-weekly-data-conversion-extra-line-in-output

Answer (score 2):

```
df['week_date-Week']=pd.to_datetime(df['Week_Number'].astype(str)+df['Year'].astype(str).add('-1') ,format='%V%G-%u')
```

Answer (score 1):

try via `apply()` and `datetime.strptime()` method:

```
import datetime

df = df.reset_index()

df['week_date']=(df[['Year','Week_Number']].astype(str)
                 .apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime('-W'.join(x) + '-1', "%Y-W%W-%w"),1))

df = df.set_index(['Year', 'Week_Number'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use `dt.strftime` with '%V'

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['27-07-2020'])).dt.strftime('%V')
```

Answer (score 1):

**pyspark SQL**

When data is too heavy, .apply will take a lot of time to process. I used below code to get month first date and week date starting from Monday.

```
df= df.withColumn('month_date', trunc('date', 'month'))
```

Output

```
date           month_date 
2019-05-28     2019-05-01
```

Below gets us week date from date column keeping week start from monday

```
df= df.withColumn("week_end", next_day("date", "SUN")).withColumn("week_start_date", date_sub("week_end", 6))
```

I used these on databricks . Apply took more than 2 hr on 200 billion rows data and this one took only 5 mins around