# daily to weekly data conversion extra line in output

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to convert daily data into weekly data.

[Input data](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aiw4HhkSppTin1w0KFjEDNdbJlX3?e=Qx7K6e)

**OUTPUT DATA AT PRESENT AFTER CONVERTING TO WEEKLY**

```
candle_date          open          high           low         close        volume     market_cap
0   2020-08-03  11059.658520  11903.881608  11011.841384  11653.660942  125051146775  1483987715241
1   2020-08-10  11665.874956  12047.515879  11199.052457  11906.236593  141819289223  1513036354035
2   2020-08-17  11915.898402  12382.422676  11435.685834  11671.520767  136888268138  1533135548697
3   2020-08-24  11668.211439  11806.669046  11183.114210  11704.963980  122232543594  1490089199926
4   2020-08-31  11713.540300  12044.196936   9951.201578  10277.329333  161912442921  1434502733759
5   2020-09-07  10268.987088  10571.363444   9926.278621  10329.126977  135512291991  1334895031420
6   2020-09-14  10331.777985  11142.177559  10289.765211  10930.445606  127131718855  1401073350332
7   2020-09-21  10932.244952  10988.397160  10193.936391  10776.149827  102033810841  1376042600278
8   2020-09-28  10780.721909  10943.369143  10441.338719  10681.900231   98068912104  1386134190290
9   2020-10-05  10686.151570  11448.963629  10567.849651  11391.338625   98896903891  1408764136859
10  2020-10-12  11408.073745  11702.355968  11250.839184  11505.137169   98218840528  1482356082955
11  2020-10-19  11512.286248  13328.197664  11439.930796  13044.753577  120381596633  1612712152389
12  2020-10-26  13045.618054  13982.123774  12849.270459  13736.162064  124757879607  1739909175360
13  2020-11-02  13756.871737  15896.270244  13285.020803  15512.313168  154877414433  1879970925027
14  2020-11-09  15488.829605  16468.996043  14894.123459  15987.469530  141569970465  2049787761252
15  2020-11-16  15978.595735  18946.038191  15920.231821  18434.821032  185169114871  2286826865664
16  2020-11-23  18407.828030  19448.948820  16386.257428  18175.177615  196158426466  2352342481120
17  2020-11-30  18190.154017  19870.271974  18190.154017  19329.346198  162863092644  2472557804161
18  2020-12-07  19368.418168  19407.188902  17636.253366  19161.698381  134594374125  2425087178385
19  2020-12-14  19157.248310  24180.203233  19038.001552  23551.884122  199825501060  2766626338521
20  2020-12-21  23495.513201  28290.731607  22175.299339  26373.295552  248021504635  3123783223081
21  2020-12-28  26286.355146  29228.074651  26104.801854  28994.354904  143235015496  2037163776668
22  2021-01-04  33002.191893  42044.987898  29297.126804  38505.490854  463910300383  4770795166629
23  2021-01-11  38404.623392  39807.999508  30677.370890  35842.139511  423220830998  4788638683820
24  2021-01-18  35796.241017  37608.310832  28958.480627  32253.599529  305897813249  4463387329238
25  2021-01-25  32235.285552  38293.042142  29433.264710  33053.678005  325358065093  4264322248817
26  2021-02-01  33024.539809  40727.557250  32371.868668  38802.513875  308464750409  4717143404739
27  2021-02-08  38761.241443  49361.316708  37995.957684  48633.123438  444165476661  5928156580184
28  2021-02-15  48584.561444  58278.652780  46281.564060  57487.962262  421367637250  6733308362825
29  2021-02-22  57484.697906  57484.697906  43297.463178  45068.045105  504129043351  6529673324222
30  2021-03-01  45132.929557  52442.430975  45132.929557  51271.669501  326776301418  6337612755799
31  2021-03-08  50958.066243  61614.249255  49397.037246  59514.205953  380963549482  7276432050879
32  2021-03-15  59219.008001  60440.721902  53542.217633  57403.979497  396322149065  7554505359750
33  2021-03-22  57383.198161  58187.279648  50801.836712  55740.751752  401834487405  7117402581409
34  2021-03-29  55727.580269  60086.034633  54987.951725  58159.061364  374014203328  7578132184715
35  2021-04-05  58180.214236  61130.297337  55677.682008  60056.725726  381067196428  7671456361743
36  2021-04-12  60101.741303  65028.971086  54066.016341  56595.127977  500261080647  8128165612019
37  2021-04-19  56655.521838  58090.475395  47618.299807  49064.521500  431184883808  7051593068660
38  2021-04-26  49129.491629  58472.106784  49129.491629  56699.654418  327779732131  7155085497481
39  2021-05-03  56680.607474  59558.490605  53643.447824  58526.911153  447235907775  7449015980647
40  2021-05-10  58562.404234  59687.499024  44231.293934  46424.219847  488043969017  6895933351605
41  2021-05-17  46550.004095  46550.004095  31535.996750  34956.668202  590920171614  5349157248865
42  2021-05-24  34864.600316  39775.552408  34819.982781  38249.915796  126113608061  1377661868066
43  2022-01-03  28966.955876  34566.831278  28812.981788  33048.027784  140017553043  1681717689684
```

The last line in the output shouldn't appear as there is no data in the input data set that is for the year 2022.

The code used to achieve the daily to weekly conversion is below:

```py
def convert_dailydata_to_weeklydata(daily_data):
    # Print function name
    print_func_name("convert_dailydata_to_weeklydata")

    # Loop over the rows until a row with Monday as date is present
    row_counter_start = 0
    while True:
        if datetime.weekday(daily_data['candle_date'][row_counter_start]) == 0:
            break
        row_counter_start += 1

    # # Loop over the rows until a row with Sunday as date is present
    # row_counter_end = len(daily_data.index) - 1
    # while True:
    #     if datetime.weekday(daily_data['candle_date'][row_counter_end]) == 6:
    #         break
    #     row_counter_end -= 1
    # print(daily_data)
    # print(row_counter_end)

    # Copy all rows after the first Monday row of data is reached
    daily_data_temp = daily_data[row_counter_start:]

    # Getting week number
    daily_data_temp['Week_Number'] = pd.to_datetime(daily_data_temp['candle_date']).dt.week

    # Getting year. Weeknum is common across years to we need to create unique index by using year and weeknum
    daily_data_temp['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(daily_data_temp['candle_date']).dt.year

    # Grouping based on required values
    df = daily_data_temp.groupby(['Year', 'Week_Number']).agg({'open': 'first', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'last', 'volume': 'sum', 'market_cap': 'sum'})

    # Reset index
    df = df.reset_index()

    # Create week date (start of week)
    # The + "1" isfor the day of the week.Week numbers 0-6 with 0 being Sunday and 6 being Saturday.
    df['week_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'].astype(str) + df['Week_Number'].astype(str) + "1", format='%G%V%w')

    # Set indexes
    df = df.set_index(['Year', 'Week_Number'])

    # Re-order columns into a new dataframe
    weekly_data = df[["week_date", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "market_cap"]]
    weekly_data = weekly_data.rename({'week_date': 'candle_date'}, axis=1)

    # Drop index columns
    weekly_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    return weekly_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   def convert_dailydata_to_weeklydata(daily_data):
        # Print function name
        SupportMethods.print_func_name()

        # Loop over the rows until a row with Monday as date is present
        row_counter_start = 0
        while True:
            if datetime.weekday(daily_data['candle_date'][row_counter_start]) == 0:
                break
            row_counter_start += 1

        # # Loop over the rows until a row with Sunday as date is present
        # row_counter_end = len(daily_data.index) - 1
        # while True:
        #     if datetime.weekday(daily_data['candle_date'][row_counter_end]) == 6:
        #         break
        #     row_counter_end -= 1
        # print(daily_data)
        # print(row_counter_end)

        # Copy all rows after the first Monday row of data is reached
        daily_data_temp = daily_data[row_counter_start:]

        # Getting week number
        daily_data_temp['Week_Number'] = pd.to_datetime(daily_data_temp['candle_date']).dt.week

        # Getting year. Weeknum is common across years to we need to create unique index by using year and weeknum
        daily_data_temp['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(daily_data_temp['candle_date']).dt.year

        # Grouping based on required values
        df = daily_data_temp.groupby(['Year', 'Week_Number']).agg(
            {'open': 'first', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min', 'close': 'last', 'volume': 'sum', 'market_cap': 'sum'})

        # Reset index
        df = df.reset_index()

        # Create week date (start of week)
        # The + "1" isfor the day of the week.Week numbers 0-6 with 0 being Sunday and 6 being Saturday.
        df['week_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'].astype(str) + df['Week_Number'].astype(str) + "1", format='%G%V%w')

        # Set indexes
        df = df.set_index(['Year', 'Week_Number'])

        # Re-order columns into a new dataframe
        weekly_data = df[["week_date", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "market_cap"]]
        weekly_data = weekly_data.rename({'week_date': 'candle_date'}, axis=1)

        # Drop index columns
        weekly_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        # Return data by dropping curent week's data
        if datetime.weekday(weekly_data.head(-1)['candle_date']) != 0:
            return weekly_data.head(-1)
        else:
            return weekly_data
```